# how to write a list of list to excel using imap and map

Tags: r, purrr

I have a list of list and I would like to input them into muti excel files, wherer excel name will be the sublist name, and name of each sheet in the excel will be the df name in each sublist. I tried to utilize `imap` and `map` to reach my goal. However I am new to those and still confuse how to set it up correctly.

**The sample list can be build using**

```
lst1<-list(`101-01-101` = list(Demographics = structure(list(SubjectID = c("Subject ID", 
"101-01-101"), BRTHDTC = c("Birthday", "1953-07-07"), SEX = c("Gender", 
"Female")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), DiseaseStatus = structure(list(SubjectID = c("Subject ID", 
"101-01-101"), DSDT = c("DS Date", "2016-03-14"), DSDT_P = c("DS Date Prob", 
NA)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))), `101-02-102` = list(Demographics = structure(list(SubjectID = c("Subject ID", 
"101-02-102"), BRTHDTC = c("Birthday", "1963-07-02"), SEX = c("Gender", 
"Female")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), DiseaseStatus = structure(list(SubjectID = c("Subject ID", 
"101-02-102"), DSDT = c("DS Date", "2017-04-04"), DSDT_P = c("DS Date Prob", 
NA)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))), `101-03-103` = list(Demographics = structure(list(SubjectID = c("Subject ID", 
"101-03-103"), BRTHDTC = c("Birthday", "1940-09-11"), SEX = c("Gender", 
"Male")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), DiseaseStatus = structure(list(SubjectID = c("Subject ID", 
"101-03-103"), DSDT = c("DS Date", NA), DSDT_P = c("DS Date Prob", 
"UN-UNK-2015")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))), `101-04-104` = list(Demographics = structure(list(
    SubjectID = c("Subject ID", "101-04-104"), BRTHDTC = c("Birthday", 
    "1955-12-31"), SEX = c("Gender", "Male")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), DiseaseStatus = structure(list(
    SubjectID = c("Subject ID", "101-04-104"), DSDT = c("DS Date", 
    "2016-05-02"), DSDT_P = c("DS Date Prob", NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))), `104-05-201` = list(
    Demographics = structure(list(SubjectID = c("Subject ID", 
    "104-05-201"), BRTHDTC = c("Birthday", "1950-12-04"), SEX = c("Gender", 
    "Female")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame")), DiseaseStatus = structure(list(SubjectID = c("Subject ID", 
    "104-05-201"), DSDT = c("DS Date", "2018-07-06"), DSDT_P = c("DS Date Prob", 
    NA)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame"))))
```

The codes I have so far are:

```
lst1 %>% imap ( ~  wb = createWorkbook()
  Map(function(data, nameofsheet){     
    addWorksheet(wb, nameofsheet)
    writeData(wb, nameofsheet, data)
}, .x, names(.x))

saveWorkbook(wb, file.path("C:/Users/SQ/Documents/",
                sprintf("subject_%s.xlsx", .y)))
)
```

My codes doesn't work, but hopfully can give you some idea what I try to do. I need to go through this in this way as I need to add some format to the sheets. Would anyone give me some guidance on how to do this?

I probably did not use `.x` & `.y` right. I am still confused on how to define them when we work with list.

Many thanks.

Comment: I noticed two functions in your code `createWorkbook` and `addWorksheet` and I was wondering what package they belong to?

Comment: I think they are from `openxlsx`

Comment: To be honest, my codes stuck at the very begini9ng where  I try to setup wb. not sure how I should handle this within imap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just need a simple tweak to the code

1. If we are using multiple expressions, block it inside the `{}`
2. The `data` going into the `Map` should be `.x` and not `.y` as `.y` will be names of the `list`

---

```
library(openxlsx)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
lst1 %>% 
   imap ( ~ { 
   wb <- createWorkbook()
   Map(function(data, nameofsheet){     
       addWorksheet(wb, nameofsheet)
       writeData(wb, nameofsheet, data)
      }, .x, names(.x))

   saveWorkbook(wb, file.path("C:/Users/SQ/Documents/",
                sprintf("subject_%s.xlsx", .y)))
                }
  )
```

-output files generated

[image]

-file content

[image]

Comment: I see. I am missing `{` and `}` for imap. Still learning. :D

Comment: If I want to allow overwrite, where should i add that? I tried `   saveWorkbook(wb, file.path("C:/Users/SQ/Documents/", sprintf("subject_%s.xlsx", .y), overwrite = TRUE))` but seems not working

Comment: @Stataq In the current code you are only writing once

Comment: I want to allow overwrite in case that I have a file with same name under that directory.

Comment: @Stataq according to the documentation the syntax is `saveWorkbook(wb, file, overwrite = FALSE, returnValue = FALSE)` so `overwrite` should work.  Only thing is that your `overwrite = TRUE` should be outside the `file.path` `)` i..e `saveWorkbook(wb, file.path("C:/Users/SQ/Documents/", sprintf("subject_%s.xlsx", .y)), overwrite = TRUE)`

Comment: One more question outside this post, how do you master what is inside `()` or outside of it. I often ran into the problem missing`) ` or ,put the things in the wrong place. Any tips on how to overcome this problem?

Comment: @Stataq It is just by looking at the code because you have closed `sprintf` and not `file.path` and there is no argument for `overwrite` inside `file.path`.  Sometimes, it is hard to pinpoint, but this code is easier as it is 2 line code.  First thing I checked was the syntax of `saveWorkbook`.  Once that was checked, I knew that it is somthing related to the placement of overwrite and thus found it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232905/discussion-between-stataq-and-akrun).